# How long until a 1031'd property can be a primary residence?

Tags: united-states, 1031-exchange, utah

I'm hoping to 1031 a rental property and then move into it myself for a bit. As far as I can tell this is fine, even when setting the mortgage to "primary residence" but how can I find out for sure? I want to make sure I don't bet hit with a minimum-wait before I can move in and work on the place etc etc.

The rental is in Utah but I'm not sure where I will be 1031ing to just yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an investment property so the "like kind" of a 1031 exchange would have to be another investment property.  If you want to convert the new investment property into a principal residence and meet the IRS safe harbor, you'd need to rent the new place out for 2 years before converting it (see [Moving into a 1031 Swap Residence](https://www.investopedia.com/financial-edge/0110/10-things-to-know-about-1031-exchanges.aspx#toc-moving-into-a-1031-swap-residence)). You could be more aggressive and move in sooner, forgoing the safe harbor, if you have other evidence that it was a bona fide investment property. But the existence of this question would cut against that possibility.

Comment: Is there such a thing as an owner occupied rental? I suspect you would get taxed on the portion the owner assumes eg 50% tax credit for a duplex, 66% for a triplex, etc etc

Comment: @Jacksonkr - What tax credit are you talking about here?  The capital gains exclusion for a primary residence?  At some point, you'd realistically want to sit down with a tax professional to walk through your particular situation because this is not a particularly simple area of tax law.

Comment: Excuse me, *capital gains exclusion* is what I meant. I have reached out to my CPA on this issue as well and am waiting their reply. In the meantime [I have found an article that seems to corroborate your point quite well](https://inside1031.com/1031-exchange-into-primary-residence/). Thanks @JustinCave